# Is a gentleman a "cowboy"?

Tags: etimología

Since "caballo" means "horse" and a "caballero" is a gentleman, is the origin of the word that the "lords" rode (whereas the common rabble walked)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `cowboy` is a `vaquero`, the one that leads the cattle. `Caballero` has nowadays the meaning of "gentleman", and the word comes from "horse" but actually not the horses used to ride (*equus –i*), but the ones used for the hard work (*caballus –i*).

> **Caballero**, del latín **caballarĭus**, es una persona que va a caballo o que cabalga. Dado que, en la antigüedad, la persona que montaba a caballo pertenecía a una cierta clase social, el concepto adquirió diversas connotaciones y significados.

<sub>[source: Definicion.de](http://definicion.de/caballero/)</sub>

> **Caballus** venía a su vez del griego kaballes –ou, con el significado igualmente de **caballo de trabajo**. El guerrero era un hombre noble que había servido como paje y escudero. La palabra Knight (caballero en inglés) deriva de la palabra anglosajona *Cnight*, que significa sirviente.

<sub>[source: wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caballero#Etimolog.C3.ADa)</sub>

The key is on the first quote, that explains how the word acquired, by association, certain connotations and thus its actual meaning.

Comment: There are other words associated with positive values derived from social conditions: _rico_ ("tasty"), _noble_ ("high-minded"), _dama_ (in Chile "decent woman" sexually), _villano_ ("wicked"), and probably more.

Answer (score 4):

I think the historical context you're missing is that "caballero" is similar in spirit to the french "chevalier" which implies horse as well (cheval in french) but really means knight. So you can think of caballero as gentleman in a modern context, but historically refers to knights.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it does. In the medieval era it was common for nobles (including knights) had access to the best education available, which meant they had better manners than commoners.

Comment: So what is the precise literal translation of "caballero" to English? According to google translate, both "horseman" and "horse rider" are "Jinete"

Comment: The precise translation would be knight @B.ClayShannon